# Is there a way for grouping in pandas using minimum difference among days?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, grouping

I explain better: I have a DataFrame with those column: **date** (date of the year), **groc** (a float value) and a third column **dif**, the difference in days between the dates. This last value spans from 0 to 20.
I would like to find an easy way to group my Dataframe using block of minimum 7 days, for example:

```
    date        groc    day         dif
2   2020-09-18  7.94    Friday      1.0
3   2020-09-19  13.43   Saturday    1.0
4   2020-09-22  14.14   Tuesday     3.0
5   2020-09-23  3.07    Wednesday   1.0
6   2020-09-24  7.79    Thursday    1.0
7   2020-09-25  9.17    Friday      1.0
8   2020-09-26  10.44   Saturday    1.0
9   2020-09-28  3.13    Monday      2.0
10  2020-10-05  20.56   Monday      7.0
```

In this case I would like to group like this:

```
2   2020-09-18  7.94    Friday      1.0
3   2020-09-19  13.43   Saturday    1.0
4   2020-09-22  14.14   Tuesday     3.0
5   2020-09-23  3.07    Wednesday   1.0
6   2020-09-24  7.79    Thursday    1.0.
```

The sum of **dif** parameter is exactly 7.

Then the next group would be:

```
7   2020-09-25  9.17    Friday      1.0
8   2020-09-26  10.44   Saturday    1.0
9   2020-09-28  3.13    Monday      2.0
10  2020-10-05  20.56   Monday      7.0
```

Note that the sum of **dif** parameter is more than 7 cause the last value summed exceed 7, it is actually 11 (1+1+2+7).

I tried to do it with a function but the result is messy and prone to errors, I would like to know if there is a more 'cleaner' way.

Comment: What if the first value in `dif` is 8? What is the first two values are `5` and `15`?

Comment: If the first value is 8 than I take only the first row. If the first and the second values are 5 and 15 than I have to take both rows cause 5 is < 7.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have the nice `dif` column, you could compute the cumsum modulo 7, then compute the `diff` and if this one is below 0 this means your need to start a new group:

```
grouper = (df['dif'].cumsum()%7).diff(1).lt(0).cumsum()

df.groupby(grouper)
```

output:

```
# group 0
           date   groc        day  dif
  2  2020-09-18   7.94     Friday  1.0
  3  2020-09-19  13.43   Saturday  1.0
  4  2020-09-22  14.14    Tuesday  3.0
  5  2020-09-23   3.07  Wednesday  1.0

# group 1
           date   groc       day  dif
  6  2020-09-24   7.79  Thursday  1.0
  7  2020-09-25   9.17    Friday  1.0
  8  2020-09-26  10.44  Saturday  1.0
  9  2020-09-28   3.13    Monday  2.0
 10  2020-10-05  20.56    Monday  7.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sadly I can't upvote cause I'm new in Stackoverflow. Thank you, your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: @NicolòRetis no worries, you can accept the answer though if it helped you ;)